# How can I estimate a linear regression that includes a lagged dependent variable?

Tags: econometrics, autocorrelation

I am interested in estimating a model of the following form:

$y_t = \beta x_t + \gamma y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

where $x_t$ represents several independent variables. The problem is that I am worried about autocorrelation, and I know that with a lagged dependent variable, Cochrane-Orcutt estimates might be inconsistent. What can I do?

Comment: There are several ways such a model can originate, and some of them lead serial correlation of the errors (e.g., a geometric lag model for the effect of the $x_t$.)  Is this the case here?  I suspect it is because of your reference to Cochrane-Orcutt.  If so, you might want to write the error term out explicitly so others don't have to figure it out for themselves!